# how to parse string into json object javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse this string into a JSON:

```
 "{'firstname':'Jesper','surname':'Aaberg','phone':'555-0100'}"
```

I'm doing it like so:

```
var strJSON = "{'firstname':'Jesper','surname':'Aaberg','phone':'555-0100'}";
console.log(JSON.parse(strJSON));
```

But I get the error message:

> VM652:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()

Does anybody know what am I missing and how can i solve it?

Comment: The JSON is invalid. You should use _double_ quotes in it, not single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace single quotes to double quotes and parse it.

```js
var str =  "{'firstname':'Jesper','surname':'Aaberg','phone':'555-0100'}";

var o = JSON.parse(str.replace(/\'/g, "\""));
console.log(o)
```

Comment: thanks man! that what i'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes are not valid for strings, you need to use double quotes instead:

```
var strJSON = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":"555-0100"}';
```

Comment: For clarity, I'd wrap your answer in single quotes, since he does want to parse a string of JSON. I couldn't actually suggest an edit since it was only two characters.

Comment: Good point, I made the change.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your string:

```
"{'firstname':'Jesper','surname':'Aaberg','phone':'555-0100'}"
```

to:

```
'{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":"555-0100"}'
```

JSON only supports double-quotes

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":"555-0100"}';

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Use this.